# Form reset is not happening

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jsp

While I try to reset the form using javascript it is not happening.

Code:
document.getElementById("formId").reset();

Result:
while I try executing the same it says undefined in the console.
And also form didn't get reset.

Also I have tried checking
document.getElementById("formId").tagName;
to verify if it is a form. I can see the same as 'Forum in the console

Comment: could you please share your html?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.